How can spatial dimensions both expand and contract for the same observer at the same time?
Suppose a lamp emits a single wavelength (monochromatic light).
The wavelength is A meters.
Next to the lamp lies a stick, also of length A.
Now we drive by the lamp at constant speed v, and then the stick, in that order.
We observe that the wavelength is now longer than A (red-shifted).
We observe that the stick is now shorter than A (length-contracted).
Somehow, two physical dimensions have changed size in opposite directions, along the same axis.
Is there a paradox here? How can simple measurable things both expand and shrink in the same space, for the same observer?

For reference:
When you move away from a light-source the frequency drops. However c = λ*f stays constant.
Therefore lambda must increase by this amount, known as red-shifting:
λ-red-shifted = λ-original * sqrt((c + v)/(c - v))
The length of the stick contracts by this amount due to v:
stick-shortened = stick-original * sqrt(1 - v^2/c^2)

Are you sure the light wouldn’t blueshift instead, depending on the direction you’re moving toward/away from the source? I will tell you that Einstein did treat problems very similar to this in the original book Relativity; have you read it or a text analyzing it?

Yes, we move away from the source. From text: "we drive by the lamp at constant speed v, and then the stick, in that order".  I have read your reference but it doesn't mention this case, but does take up another paradox, the rigid wheel, but leaves it unresolved.

Okay. Just for reference, “by” and “next to” do not specify direction, which in this case is important to resolving the question. You might want to be more specific. Two, having just reread Relativity I can confirm that the rigid wheel is in no way violating relativity, and three, what exactly is the issue you’re encountering? Why can’t length contract in concert with redshift?

We pass the lamp first, then the stick, so the direction of v is given.

Redshift is not just the relativistic change of wavelength. It's an additional effect, that depends on your direction of motion.

The observed-wavelength (separation between lightlike signal-lines)
doesn't directly involve length-contraction (involving parallel timelike-lines).
See https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/337602/deriving-relativistic-doppler-effect-through-length-contraction

You might as well ask how the Doppler effect can cause the shortening of the wavelength of sound at non-relativistic speeds where there is no length contraction! Length contraction and the Doppler effect are unrelated phenomena, so there is no contradiction between them. Length contraction is a geometrical property of spacetime which causes spatial distances to be frame-dependent. Your mistake is assuming that the Doppler effect is the result of length contraction, which it is not.
Addendum
Length contraction applies where you have two points, fixed relative to each other in their own rest frame, moving at some speed v through your frame, where v is less than c. You seem to be assuming that applies to a wavelength of light, which is nonsense. A wavelength of light is not two fixed points moving at a speed v.

I can't do line-breaks so apologies for the messy look.

"you might as well ask how the Doppler effect can cause a shortening of the wavelength of sound without length contraction"

The wavelength of sound is unaffected by air-doppler.
Soundwaves are ruled by classical doppler, which sets wavelength constant and only frequency changes.

"you assume the Doppler effect is the result of length contraction"

This is absurd. No one claims this, I'm sorry.

"Length contraction and doppler effect are unrelated phenomena"

Strongly agree, thanks for taking the time +1

Thanks Harry. You say no-one claims the Doppler effect is caused by length contraction, but on the other hand you seem to be asking why isn't the wavelength length contracted!

I'm simply observing that space can accommodate 'length-extension' and length-contraction at the same time in the same place. It takes great elasticity to accomplish such a feat.

Here's a spacetime diagram that models your scenario.
It's drawn on “rotated graph paper” so that we can count the ticks along segments.
Suggested by my comment to the OP,
there is a distinction of these lengths:

The observed-length of an object (like a ruler)
is the measured spatial separation between parallel timelike-lines (the worldlines of the front and back of the object).

The observed-wavelength of a light wave
is the measured spatial separation between parallel lightlike-lines (associated with two successive signals received from a periodic source).


Below is a situation where the source observer
emits a signal with a period of 10-ticks
so that
the wavelength [the spatial separation between lightlike-signals]
is $$\lambda_{source}=c(10 {\rm ticks})= 10\ \mbox{space-ticks} = 10 \mbox{ sticks}.$$
He obtains a ruler whose proper-length [the separation between parallel timelike-worldlines of the ruler ends in the rest frame of the ruler] is $L_{stick}=10\ \mbox{sticks}$, which was chosen to be equal to that wavelength $\lambda_{source}$.
In the source frame, an inertial receiver has velocity $v=(3/5)c$, as shown.

What does that receiver measure for the wavelength and for the ruler-length?

We construct the spatial-axis of the moving inertial receiver.

We note that for $(v/c)=(3/5)$,
we have $\gamma=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-(v/c)^2}}=5/4$ and $k=\sqrt{\frac{1+(v/c)}{1-(v/c)}}=2$.
As the receiver approaches the source, the receiver measures

an apparent ruler-length of 8 sticks, ($(L/\gamma)=(10/(5/4))=8$)
as represented by OL (the spatial separation of the ruler-worldlines)
a wavelength of 5 sticks,
as represented by OW' (the spatial separation of the successive lightlike-signal-lines)
that are measured by the receiver during the approach.

The approaching receiver encounters the backward-directed signals.

Note the receiver measures a period of 5 ticks, so the ratio of periods $T_{obs}/T_{src}=5/10=1/2$, and thus the ratio of frequencies $f_{obs}/f_{src}$ is 2…  blueshifted.

After the receiver passes the source and is now departing the source, the receiver measures

an apparent ruler-length of 8 sticks, ($(L/\gamma)=(10/(5/4))=8$)
as represented by OL (the spatial separation of the ruler-worldlines)… indeed $\gamma$ is an even function of $v$.
a wavelength of 20 sticks,
as represented by OW (the spatial separation of the successive lightlike-signal-lines)
that are measured by the receiver during the departure.

The departing receiver encounters the forward-directed signals.

Note the receiver measures a period of 20 ticks, so the ratio of periods $T_{obs}/T_{src}=20/10=2$, and thus the ratio of frequencies $f_{obs}/f_{src}$ is 1/2… redshifted.

So, I think his apparent paradox is based on a misconception that does not recognize the distinction between the length of an object and the wavelength of a light wave.
(The diagram above is a variant of the one I made for my answer to
Deriving Relativistic Doppler Effect through length contraction )
Here's a spacetime diagram for the receiver's frame.
I've included the worldline of the receiver's 10-stick ruler to help show the symmetry of length-contraction.


All your numbers are 100% correct. We use the same equations for everything so we'll always agree on what's observed.
The mystery I'm trying to get at is that two quantities, both measured in meters, react so differently to my relative speed.
Your diagram is great. It may well give me additional insight so I will try to follow your details. To be continued

@harry “A spacetime diagram is worth a thousand words”. Often it clarifies the meaning of the symbols and of their relationships in an equation.

ok, I think I follow what the diagram says. It's a nice way of tracking the issue in a graphical way, which is cool.  (recap for my own benefit)
When observers move right, their time'-axis tilts down towards the light-line, and the space'-axis tilts up by the same amount.
The two tilted axes are symmetrical about the 45-degree light-line.
The tilted t'-axis shows plainly that the moving observer must wait longer between wavefronts.

With sound, this drop in frequency is caused by the slower approach of wavefronts.

With light, the wavefronts approach the observer at the same rate. A slower frequency demands a longer wavelength.

That's the core issue: The diagram uses the tilt of the t'-axis to set the change in the x'-direction.
This is only done for wavelenghts.
For all other x-dimensions it uses the tilt of the x'-axis (simultaneity line) to graph the contraction.
But for the physical x-dimension of wavelengths an exception is made.

It's really a weird paradox. I imagine taking a picture of the monochromatic light, and printing out a nice sinusoid.
Now the picture of the sinusoid is time-independent, and will therefore get length-contracted the regular way.
Meanwhile, an actual physical wavelength is not.

@harry The spacetime diagram was developed by Hermann Minkowski in 1907 as a geometric way to interpret Einstein’s Special Relativity. The rotated graph paper and diamonds are my supplements to help visualize the calculations implied by Minkowski spacetime geometry and various formulas of special relativity by counting diamonds. We need to practice to model and interpret the world relativistically. Using the spacetime diagram helps us to do this.

Just to give you a partial answer that I hope is somewhat instructive, I want to point out that length contraction doesn't always happen in relativity, and especially with moving objects.
And one of your objects, is light: it is the thing that can't stop moving, in this theory.
Suppose that I am in a spaceship occupying some inertial reference frame and I think that there is a space rock moving past me that is 1 km long. And it is zooming by at $\gamma = 2$ and I have to clarify that it is 1 km long in my frame of reference, but due to length contraction it is 2km long in its frame.
Now you come along with $\gamma=2$, what do you see?
Well, it depends on which direction you're going!
If you're coming in opposed to the motion of the rock, then to you it contracts further, looking (2/7) km long. Note that if I furnished a 1km measuring stick that happened to be instantaneously next to the rock for me (but stationary), it would on your account be significantly longer than the rock, 0.5 km as compared to 0.28 km, as it wouldn't get contracted by as much.
But if you're coming in moving in the same direction as the rock, for you it de-contracts to its rest length of 2 km, meanwhile my measuring stick is still only 0.5 km long.
This is all to say that if you were thinking of some sort of homogeneous isotropic length contraction, that's definitely not what we're describing here!
In terms of actually understanding it, I think different students require different insights before they suddenly “get it.” For me the insight was that the two edges of a rigid body form parallel lines on a spacetime chart $x$ vs $w=ct$, and those do Lorentz-transform to other parallel lines, and as they “tilt” they kind of “crowd together” while as they “untilt” they spread apart, this felt very unintuitive. But my “aha” that made it all click for me, was to look in the rest frame where the two lines are maximally un-tilted, they are in the $\hat w$-direction. And then I thought, “because of the relativity of simultaneity, moving observers have a present which is not in the $\hat x$ direction, and so they draw the diagonal line of “now” between these two lines at some angle, why don't they see the distance between the two as longer?” So the diagram that makes it click for me looks like this:

And the question is, why isn't that dotted blue line longer than the, in this case, 4 units between the two lines. And that is entirely due to the Lorentzian shape of the metric, it's $$\Delta s^2 = \Delta x^2 - \Delta w^2,$$ so the diagonal in this direction actually reduces the measured length commensurately.
So that meant a lot to me and probably doesn't mean so much to you! But just keep working problems in relativity and you will eventually find a perspective that clicks.

Thank you for a great example of how length-contraction works.
We very much agree that a moving object can be made to expand, or contract, based on the observer's relative speed.

Yep! If it answers your Q of “How can simple measurable things both expand and shrink in the same space, for the same observer?” please mark as accepted, if it just pushes the Q further down please edit the question to be more focused on those aspects and that'll make it more helpful for people searching the site.

I edited the question to highlight the core issue: The strange elasticity of space to allow both expansion and contraction at the same time, by two different mechanisms. It's hard to convey the strangeness of this situation in a short title though.

It's very important to understand that the space itself is not expanding/contracting, rather you are seeing the leading and trailing edges of the object at different times. So for example in the diagram I drew, if the red lines were colored instead like a rainbow , reflecting an object that is homogeneously changing color, the moving observer (after correcting for Doppler etc) sees an object that is not all of one color, and this is key to “how why do these change differently”: compared to you I am seeing the leading/trailing edge at different times!

There should be no "correcting for Doppler" for the length of the object in your example (distance between red lines). The length-altering effect of Doppler simply doesn't apply to the color-changing object shown as stationary in your diagram, regardless of the observer's speed. I don't quite see how your red lines play a different role than the 'stick' in the original text. Both contract the same amount by the observer's speed (or expand if observer slows down)


Consider this diagram: three wavelengths of a photon. Let the bottom rod (green) be at rest relative to the observer, and the top rod (blue) be moving with $\gamma=1.5$, contracting it to two-thirds of its original length. The photon is not redshifted at all here.
Note that, measured by the contracted rod (or measured by us if the light source and contracted rod are comoving/if we are moving past the light source and rod at relativistic speed), the photon’s frequency has decreased: over the same distance (one rod), the photon oscillates only twice as opposed to three times. This equates to redshift: as measured with the contracted rod (or as measured with a regular rod and a fast-moving light source), the frequency goes down and the wavelength goes up.

This is not a perfect representation - it wasn’t meant to be. But it does show that redshift and length contraction are due to the same phenomenon and can, without issue, appear together.

Your example uses length-contraction to determine what wavelength the blue rod will see. That is not right.

It's ok to use your numbers. Blue rod moves at .7c (=2/3 length-contraction) away from the light-source (to match my example). In that case the blue rod would observe a wavelength almost 6 times longer than the green rod. In other words, only half of one wavelength would match the length of the blue rod. The diagram above gets that wrong.
For completeness, the blue rod sees the green rod contracted by 2/3 - AND it would see 6x longer wavelenghts.
That goes to the core of my question, since things grow AND shrink in the same space at the same time.

We’re actually agreeing: yes, I got the precise numbers wrong, but the point was to demonstrate that redshift is actually on par with length contraction because the measuring rods you’re using to define wavelength are getting shorter, just producing a longer wavelength. Note that a single wavelength of light doesn’t act as a measuring rod on its own.

It might not seem perfectly intuitive but this is the result one obtains after applying SR, which is one part of the physical theory that almost-perfectly describes the macroscopic world we observe.


redshift is actually on par with length contraction  -- I disagree. They work in opposite directions, which is the key point, and why I posted this. Blueshift is on par with length-contraction (both wavelength and stick shrink). Yet even there the contraction due to doppler is very different from regular length-contraction.  I appreciate your patience and feedback. It's ok to disagree.


You are trying to affix a measuring rod to the wavelengths of the photon - you cannot do this because the photon is moving at $c$ and there are no inertial reference frames at that speed. When the rod next to the photon contracts, there are fewer wavelengths per rod-length (which I'm sure you will agree with me on), and thus there are move rod-lengths per wavelength, thus redshift. I hate to have to say it but that's just what is observed, and unless you can provide another reasonable explanation that completely replaces relativity...

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

You can make a similar "paradox" with baguettes. If you take a baguette and slice it one way you can get slices about 6 cm long. If you slice it another way you can get slices about 60 cm long. And if you slice it diagonally you can get baguette slices of any length in between.
In spacetime an object which is moving at some non-zero velocity is oriented diagonally. The faster it is moving the more diagonal it is. Length contraction is the disagreement on the length of the object due to slicing it on a spacetime diagonal.
Now, if you have several baguettes laid out on a table at different angles, and you cut all of the baguettes with one long straight knife, then you will get different sized slices. If you change the angle of the knife then some slices may get bigger and some slices may get smaller. This is geometrically the same as the issue you describe in your question.
So, yes, some slices will get longer and other slices will get shorter, depending on the angle (velocity) in the original frame. This is a little weird, but it is a feature of ordinary Euclidean geometry too. The main difference is that in spacetime the diagonal slices are shorter rather than longer.

Baguettes make sense, and speed = degrees. When you slice the baguettes at 90 degrees they are 1 unit wide. You slice them at 45 degrees they grow to 1.4 units. Except one baguette, which turns shorter when sliced at 45 degrees. And that baguette is not even symmetrical. When you slice it at 90 + 45 it actually turns longer, but much longer than other baguettes cut at 135 degrees. I think I should rephrase the question to make the point a little clearer.

@harry With this many answers it would be very difficult to edit the question in a way that didn’t invalidate any of the answers. You should probably ask a new question, linking to this one and highlighting the difference. Regarding your comment, yes, there are subtle differences like what you point out. The 45 degree diagonals are special in Minkowski geometry and not in Euclidean geometry. But my main point that the basic "space both expands and contracts" thing happens in ordinary Euclidean geometry also. So that specific part isn't actually something weird

that's very true. I will leave this post as is, and consider a follow-up.

For an observer who is in rest relative to the stick, the phase of the light wave is the same at both ends of the stick.
However, for an observer who moves relative to the stick, the phases will not be the same because of the relativity of simultaneity.
Likewise, if the stick oscillates side-wise, for the moving observer it will be wavy, not straight.

Everything you say is true. I'm not quite sure how it applies to the question posted. It's hard to phrase the question well... let me try with this version: Given a simple physical dimension of length which I can measure with a ruler in my own kitchen, somehow this one length, of all the lengths in the world, escapes the effect of length-contraction. Feel free to correct or expand.

@harry. How would you measure the wavelength in your kitchen?

Put a chocolate in your microwave. An EM wavelength of roughly 12 cm will be stamped onto it.

@harry. That's a standing wave, not a moving wave.
